# Getting Readonly Databind using EF POCO Objects

Tags: entity-framework, data-binding, entity-framework-4, binding

I am using EF4 with WPF.  I am databinding to the DataGrid in a Master-Detail style.  Think of the Northwind Customers -> Orders -> OrderDetails.

What I am finding is that when I use POCO objects, the Orders and OrderDetails grids are read-only.  If I revert to using the designer generated entities they become editable.

The binding XAML looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomersViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:Customer, CreateList=True}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomersOrdersViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Orders, Source={StaticResource CustomersViewSource}}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource CustomersViewSource}">

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomersOrdersViewSource}}" >
```

(I've removed attributes not relevant to databinding, of course.)

Then there's the standard form load event to bind the context instance:

```
Dim NorthwindEntities As BindTest.NorthwindEntities = New BindTest.NorthwindEntities()
Dim CustomersViewSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("CustomersViewSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
CustomersViewSource.Source = NorthwindEntities.Customers
```

The grids populate, but the second is readonly if I'm using my POCO objects, editable if they are the standard EF generated objects.

The key seems to be in the navigation properties of the entities.  My POCO objects use:

```
Public Overridable Property Orders() As ICollection(Of Order)
    Get
        If _Orders Is Nothing Then  _Orders = New HashSet(Of Order)
   Return _Orders
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ICollection(Of Order))
        _Orders = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Whereas the EF objects are much more complicated:

```
<XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
<SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
<DataMemberAttribute()>
<EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("NorthwindModel", "FK_Order_Details_Orders", "Orders")>
Public Property Order() As Order
    Get
        Return CType(Me, IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference(Of Order)("NorthwindModel.FK_Order_Details_Orders", "Orders").Value
    End Get
    Set
        CType(Me, IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference(Of Order)("NorthwindModel.FK_Order_Details_Orders", "Orders").Value = value
    End Set
End Property
```

For the lack of some better wording, there seems to be some magic in either the attributes for the EntityCollection type.  ICollection isn't a readonly interface and a HashSet isn't readonly either.

Any ideas about how to get POCO to work here or am I stuck with EF derived objects?  (Makes unit testing difficult.)

Thanks.

Comment: A concrete instance of `ICollection<T>` can be readonly. It depends on the type you are instantiating the collection with. For example `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is an ICollection which is readonly. Since the setter of your POCO `Orders` property is public you could have a readonly Orders collection depending on what collection you assign to the property. How do you fill the Orders collection of a Customer object? By lazy loading?

Comment: @Slauma: Currently it is lazy loading. My first POCO template, however, had readonly navigation properites.  The property had to be using the internally created HashSet, which should have been editable.  It doesn't make sense to me to allow an external object to substitute a new collection reference for one internally managed by a class.  Hence, the original POCO class had a readonly navigation property. The HashSet was editable, but the reference to it could not be changed.  I changed the navigation property to read-write in an effort to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that the `Orders` and `OrderDetails` collections are of type `ICollection<T>` / `HashSet<T>` in your POCO example. The WPF datagrid internally does not work with the collection directly but rather with an associated "collection view". When you bind the collection to the DataGrid the WPF binding engine creates this internal collection view based on the type of the collection.

If your collection implements only `IEnumerable` or only `ICollection` the type of the created collection view is `CollectionView`, a class which does **not** implement `IEditableCollectionView`. That's the reason why you can't edit the DataGrid when you bind a HashSet to it.

The DataGrid needs a collection view which implements `IEditableCollectionView` to allow editing. This is for example the `ListCollectionView` (which also derives from `CollectionView`). WPF creates this type of collection view if your source collection implements the `IList` interface.

So, to fix the problem you should change the type of the `Orders` property of your POCO to `IList`:

```
Public Overridable Property Orders() As IList(Of Order)
    Get
        If _Orders Is Nothing Then  _Orders = New List(Of Order)
        Return _Orders
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As IList(Of Order))
        _Orders = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**Edit**

According to @Allon Guralnek's comment below it is necessary to implement the **non-generic** `IList` interface to get an editable DataGrid. This is the case for `List(Of T)`, therefore the code above will still work. Other implementations which only implement the **generic** `IList(Of T)` but not the non-generic `IList` won't make the DataGrid editable.

Comment: That fixes the issue.  I have changed my T4 template to use IList and everything is good now.  Bonus points for the detailed explanation (if I could give bonus points!).  To be honest, I'm a little uneasy with EF and WPF because they hide so much of the complexity that it is hard to find the root cause of problems.  Thank you!

Comment: @user458314: You need 7 reputation points more (15 minimum) to "give bonus points" (aka "vote up") ;) And I agree that it's often difficult to detect the origin of a problem, especially in WPF. I could only answer your question since I suddenly remembered that I had the same problem around one month ago. There was an exception when I double clicked on the DataGrid and the exception told me something about "EditItem not possible with this view" or similar. That was a little hint to start a search. It took me some time nonetheless to find the final reason.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that in order for a `DataGrid` to be editable, you must bind it to a collection that implements the __non-generic__ `IList` interface (if you only implement the generic `IList<T>`/`IList(Of T)`, then it won't be editable). The `List<T>`/`List(Of T)` class just happens to implement both.

Comment: I've changed the HashSet to List and it solved the problem - but if I ever update the TT file, I will face this problem all over again. Is there a way to make EF 6.1 to always make them Lists ?

Comment: @Dani: I believe, modifying the T4 template is the only way.

Comment: Its a bad practice... each time you'll recreate it for any reason... you'll have to redo it.

Comment: @Dani: Why would you ever want to recreate the **TT file**? Not sure if we are talking about the same. You open the model.tt file in a text editor, change "HashSet" to "List" (there is only one place where that occurs) and everytime you update your model you get a `List<T>` for your collections instead of `HashSet<T>`. The modified tt file never changes unless you do it manually or overwrite it with an old version. You don't change the generated model classes manually of course, that would be overwritten indeed if you recreate the classes after any model change.

Comment: @Slauma - each time there is an update to EF eventually I am forced to recreate everything from scratch. It's a bad practice to change auto-generated files...

Comment: @Dani: The TT files are not auto-generated.