# 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view. WPF .NET 4 / EF 4.1 - Master - Detail

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Ok, in order to try to find an answer for this question I have made an even simpler project, using the AdventureWorks database.

I created a Model from the Vendor and PurchaseOrderHeader tables - added them as a datasource to the project, and have the following code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EFDbContextTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="569" Width="1130" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:EFDbContextTest;assembly=EFDbContextTest" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="vendorViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:Vendor, CreateList=True}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="vendorPurchaseOrderHeadersViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=PurchaseOrderHeaders, Source={StaticResource vendorViewSource}}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vendorViewSource}">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="12,12,0,0" 
              Name="vendorDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1084" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              SelectedValuePath="VendorID">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="accountNumberColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=AccountNumber}" Header="Account Number" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="activeFlagColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ActiveFlag}" Header="Active Flag" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="creditRatingColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=CreditRating}" Header="Credit Rating" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="modifiedDateColumn" Header="Modified Date" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=ModifiedDate, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="preferredVendorStatusColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=PreferredVendorStatus}" Header="Preferred Vendor Status" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="purchasingWebServiceURLColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=PurchasingWebServiceURL}" Header="Purchasing Web Service URL" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="vendorIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=VendorID}" Header="Vendor ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vendorPurchaseOrderHeadersViewSource}}" Margin="12,218,0,0" Name="purchaseOrderHeadersDataGrid" 
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1084" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="employeeIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=EmployeeID}" Header="Employee ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="freightColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Freight}" Header="Freight" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="modifiedDateColumn1" Header="Modified Date" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=ModifiedDate, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="orderDateColumn" Header="Order Date" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=OrderDate, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="purchaseOrderIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=PurchaseOrderID}" Header="Purchase Order ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="revisionNumberColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=RevisionNumber}" Header="Revision Number" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="shipDateColumn" Header="Ship Date" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=ShipDate, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shipMethodIDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ShipMethodID}" Header="Ship Method ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="statusColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Header="Status" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="subTotalColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=SubTotal}" Header="Sub Total" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="taxAmtColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=TaxAmt}" Header="Tax Amt" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="totalDueColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalDue}" Header="Total Due" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="vendorIDColumn1" Binding="{Binding Path=VendorID}" Header="Vendor ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace EFDbContextTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Entities _context = new Entities();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource vendorViewSource =
                ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("vendorViewSource")));
        _context.Vendors.Include("PurchaseOrderHeaders").Load();
        vendorViewSource.Source = _context.Vendors.Local;

        }
    }
}
```

So, both grids are on the Window, you can edit/delete/update the Master grid like there's no tomorrow - as soon as you try to click into any cell on the detail grid you get the error 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

I have to be missing something here, because this happens to me in several instances where I have a Master-Detail view using EF 4.1 - help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `PurchaseOrderHeaders` collection property in your `Vendor` class is of type `ICollection<T>` then this could be source of your problem. To get a datagrid which allows editing the source collection must be of type `IList<T>` or any type which implements `IList<T>` like `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>`. You will probably need to change the collection type of `PurchaseOrderHeaders` in your model class accordingly.

More detailed explanation is here: [Getting Readonly Databind using EF POCO Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394835/getting-readonly-databind-using-ef-poco-objects/5397146#5397146)

**Edit**

According to @Allon Guralnek's comment below it is necessary to implement the **non-generic** `IList` interface to get an editable DataGrid. This is the case for `ObservableCollection<T>` and `List<T>`. Other implementations which only implement the **generic** `IList<T>` but not the non-generic `IList` won't make the DataGrid editable.

Comment: `IList<T>` won't do. The trick is to have your collection implement the non-generic `IList` interface.

Comment: @Allon: I see. I'm actually using `ObservableCollection<T>` which implements both, I guess. Thanks for clarification, I wouldn't have thought that the non-generic `IList` is the important part.