# Changing default relation type in EF 6.1

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

After upgrading to EF6.1 and recreating my edmx file, my detailed DataGrids stopped to work. I wan't able to edit them or see the "new empty row"

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508479/edititem-is-not-allowed-for-this-view-wpf-net-4-ef-4-1-master-detail) explains what happened. new EF uses HashSet to link objects so if you have 
School object that has a list of classes they will be linked as a HashSet, rendering grid functionality to... none.

The solution is simple, I've just changed in the tt file the type to List and everything started working as before.

My Question though - since I've manually changed an auto-generated file, the next time I'll re-generate it for any reason - I'll have to do it all over again.

**Is there a way to make EF 6.1 to automatically use List to link between objects ?**